# Google Maps remove marker route context menu

Tags: android, menu, maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I started a new project with the Google Maps template of Android Studio and just added a marker to the map.

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
```

When I click the Marker there comes a little menu with a Google Maps icon on the bottom right corner:

[image: the menu on the bottom right]

How can I get rid of this thing? I couldn't find anything I even don't know how to call it but I really need to get rid of it.

Comment: damn... I just didn't have seen it: mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

Answer (score 9):

You need to call [setMapToolbarEnabled](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)) method of UiSettings

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    // Do other staff
}
```