# How to remove Google Map Markers without blinking?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to populate multiple markers via ajax request on 5 sec interval. Every thing is working fine, but markers blinks on each interval call.

I am clearing all markers & regenerating again on each interval call. I just want to re-generate markers without blinking.

Also, it's possible that ajax request can return different result set on each interval call.

Following is the code:

```
  var map;
  var places;
  var markers = [];
  var iw_map;
  var markers_map = new Array();

  function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      var latlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(25.1999721, 66.8354386);
      iw_map = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var mapOptions = {
          center: latlngCenter,
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
      fetchPlaces();
      fitMapToBounds_map();
  }

  function fetchPlaces(cityId = null, hubId = null, riderId = null) {
    clearMarkers(); 
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ route('get-markers') }}',
      method:'POST',
      data: {'city_id': cityId, hub_id: hubId, rider_id: riderId},
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {

          // console.log(markers);

          var markerz = data.markers;

          // clearMarkers();

          $.each(markerz, function (i, dt) {

            var marker_icon = {url: dt.icon};
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(dt.lat,dt.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: position,
              icon: marker_icon
            });

            // newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(dt.lat,dt.lng);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) { 
              $.ajax({  
                  url: '{{ route('get-marker-info') }}',
                  method:'POST',
                  data: JSON.parse(dt.params),
                  success: function(data) {  
                      iw_map.setContent(data.infoBox);  
                      iw_map.open(map, marker);  
                  }  
              });
            });
            markers.push(marker.getPosition());
            markers_map.push(marker);
          });

          // fitMapToBounds_map();
      }  
    });

  }

  function fitMapToBounds_map() {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      if (markers.length>0) {
          for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
              console.log(markers[i]);
              bounds.extend(markers[i]);
          }
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
  } 

  function clearMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers_map.length; i++) {
      markers_map[i].setMap(null);
    }

    markers_map = [];
  }

  function loadScript_map() {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false&v=3&libraries=places&callback=initialize";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  window.onload = loadScript_map;

  setInterval(fetchPlaces, 5000);
```

Comment: First set the new markers then remove the old ones? This really depends on the performance of the client machine and number of markers you are loading. Might be that you don't even see the change, or the "blink" might be longer than just a blink...

Comment: There can be thousands of markers at same time. if I remove this part of  `clearMarkers` function `for (var i = 0; i < markers_map.length; i++) {
      markers_map[i].setMap(null);
    }`. ajax call create new markers but does not not removes the old ones which did not received in ajax response

Comment: Obviously yes. What is the point of that comment?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that, I am able to add new marker without blinking, but not able to remove old ones. let's say, initially I have 5 markers (A, B, C, D, E), on interval call I get 6 markers (A, B, C, F, G, H). in this case **F,G,H** are added but **D,E** does not removes.

Comment: That's what I said in my first comment... to avoid "blinking" you might try to **first** add the new markers **then** remove the old ones... That implies a few changes in your code of course.

Comment: can you please provide some example code (if possible) for this, as I am completely stuck here...????

Comment: I'll try. Just a side comment... why do you use `markers` and `markerz` and `markers_map`, etc.? Name your variables with meaningful names might add clarity to your code (even if it's just for you...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps remove marker route context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377823/google-maps-remove-marker-route-context-menu)

Comment: @MatejJ Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code so it might need a few adjustments.

I renamed your variables with meaningful names and changed the logic to first add the new markers, then remove the old markers.

When you get your markers with AJAX, first empty the `new_markers` array, then plot the markers on the map, and add them to the `new_markers` array. Then clear the old markers from the map (`markers` array). The first time, this array will be empty so nothing will happen. Copy `new_markers` array to `markers` array. Repeat.

Here is the code:

```
var map;
var places;
var markers_positions = [];
var markers = [];
var new_markers = [];
var iw_map;


function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var latlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(25.1999721, 66.8354386);
  iw_map = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: latlngCenter,
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  fetchPlaces();
  fitMapToBounds_map();
}

function fetchPlaces(cityId = null, hubId = null, riderId = null) {

  new_markers = [];

  $.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('get-markers') }}',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      city_id: cityId,
      hub_id: hubId,
      rider_id: riderId
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

      $.each(data.markers, function(i, dt) {

        var marker_icon = {
          url: dt.icon
        };
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(dt.lat, dt.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: position,
          icon: marker_icon
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('get-marker-info') }}',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.parse(dt.params),
            success: function(data) {
              iw_map.setContent(data.infoBox);
              iw_map.open(map, marker);
            }
          });
        });
        markers_positions.push(marker.getPosition());
        new_markers.push(marker);
        clearMarkers();
      });
    }
  });

}

function fitMapToBounds_map() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < markers_positions.length; i++) {
    console.log(markers_positions[i]);
    bounds.extend(markers_positions[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function clearMarkers() {

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }

  markers = new_markers;
}

function loadScript_map() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false&v=3&libraries=places&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript_map;

setInterval(fetchPlaces, 5000);
```